# Align bottom all shapes according to a name with VBA (Powerpoint)

Tags: vba, alignment, powerpoint

I have an issue aligning shapes using VBA on PowerPoint (office 360).

I know I can use .Shapes.Range.Align msoAlignBottom, msoFalse
but I don't understand how to make it work with a specific shape name as I always have an error or nothing is happening.

This is the code in which I would like to implement this action:

```
Sub FixFitToShape()
    Dim oSl    As Slide
    Dim sn As String
    Dim oSh    As Shape

    sn = InputBox("Enter the name of the shape")
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            If oSh.Name = sn Then
                Select Case oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                Case 1, 3 'Title
                    oSh.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape ' OR msoAutoSizeNone
                Case 2, 7 'Text / Content
                    oSh.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
                
                    oSh.Shapes.Range.Align msoAlignBottom, msoTrue

                End Select
            End If
            
        Next oSh
    Next oSl
End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: Please specify exactly what you want to do: 1) find a figure on each slide and align the other figures on this slide to the one you found, 2) find all figures on each slide with the same name and align them, 3) align all figures on all slides with the same name to the first figure, 4) another option

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just need every shape with the same name defined by sn to be aligned with the bottom of its slide. And I need that the shape is aligned after the process of msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape or msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub FixFitToShape()
    Dim oSl    As Slide
    Dim sn As String
    Dim oSh    As Shape

    'sn = InputBox("Enter the name of the shape")
    sn = "Name1"    'debug
    'On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For i = 1 To oSl.Shapes.Count
            Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(i)
            If oSh.Name = sn Then
                Select Case oSh.Type    'placeholder or not placeholder?
                    Case msoPlaceholder
                        ' it's a placeholder! check the placeholder's type
                        If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderTitle _
                            Or oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderCenterTitle Then
                            'do smth with placeholder
                            oSh.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
                        End If
                    Case Else   'it's not a placeholder
                        oSh.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
                        oSl.Shapes.Range(i).Align msoAlignBottoms, msoTrue 'align it to bottom of the slide
                End Select
            End If
        Next
    Next oSl
End Sub
```

I also recommend removing the `On Error Resume Next` statement because it hides errors and you don't get useful information about how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `ShapeRange` that includes the shapes you want to align. Since you are keying off the name of the shape, the example below shows how a wildcard can be used.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    LineUpShapes 1, "Rectangle", msoAlignTops
End Sub

Sub LineUpShapes(ByVal SlideNumber As Long, _
                 ByVal ShapeName As String, _
                 ByVal alignment As MsoAlignCmd)
    Dim sl As Slide
    Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumber)
    
    Dim namedShapes() As Variant
    Dim shapeCount As Integer
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In sl.Shapes
        If sh.Name Like (ShapeName & "*") Then
            shapeCount = shapeCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve namedShapes(shapeCount) As Variant
            namedShapes(shapeCount) = sh.Name
            Debug.Print "shape name " & sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
    
    Dim shapesToAlign As ShapeRange
    Set shapesToAlign = sl.Shapes.Range(namedShapes)
    shapesToAlign.Align alignment, msoFalse
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Алексей!

I have readapted your code and it works perfectly! It is always a placeholder in my case ;)

```
Sub FixFitToShape()
    Dim oSl    As Slide
    Dim sn As String
    Dim oSh    As Shape

    sn = InputBox("Enter the name of the shape")
  
    
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
      For i = 1 To oSl.Shapes.Count
            Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(i)
            If oSh.Name = sn Then
                Select Case oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                Case 1, 3 'Title
                    oSh.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape ' OR msoAutoSizeNone
                Case 2, 7 'Text / Content
                  oSh.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
                  oSl.Shapes.Range(i).Align msoAlignBottoms, msoTrue 'align it to bottom of the slide
     
                End Select
            End If
            
        Next
    Next oSl
    
End Sub
```